# Android can use wrong layout file for single-orientation activities

Tags: android, orientation

I discovered by accident that if you have an Activity that is set to one orientation, but contains a separate layout file for a different orientation, when the Activity is first started it will be inflated with the layout file that matches the **device's physical orientation** and **not** the layout file that matches the **Activity's** orientation.  Thus if AndroidManifest.xml specifies

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LandscapeGardener"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <!-- note for new readers: sensorLandscape is like landscape, but also
             works upside-down.
             Other activity stuff would go here. -->
    </activity>
```

and there is a layout for `LandscapeGardener` in the `layout-port` folder, if the Activity is loaded in portrait, the portrait-specific layout will be inflated.

The reason we have this situation, by the way, is that an Activity we're developing has some portrait-specific bugs, so we decided to suppress portrait mode for users while we fix them—but of course this problem makes the suppression somewhat partial!

Note that if the device is correctly oriented at startup, it will not change to the incorrect layout.

Comment: just curious, does adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` make any difference?

Comment: This is on startup; if you start in landscape it doesn't change layout.

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but LandscapeGardener means "Landscape" in a context other than orientation, right? (As in, a place that could be gardened)  Otherwise you have a landscape-locked layout in the layout-port folder.

Comment: I chose the name `LandscapeGardener` as a joke, but you're right in the sense that the `Activity` name doesn't affect the function: you could call it `PortraitPainter` as well and it would work in landscape if you set it up to.

Answer (score -1):

instead of sensorLandscape, try just landscape. i'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: I just tried it—`landscape` produces exactly the same bug as `sensorLandscape`.